# Can I add a base fee per extrinsic?

Tags: weight, fee, weighttofee

My understanding is that there is a configurable base fee which is the minimum amount that a user pays for ANY transaction.

Is there a way to add an additional base fee per extrinsic? This fee should be unrelated to the weight fee of the extrinsic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to modify your `WeightToFee` implementation.

> Note, you will probably depend on [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11415/files) being merged before you can easily do this.

But in general, there is a function which we expect the user to implement which describes how we convert some `Weight` of an extrinsic into a "free" which is some `Balance`.

In this case, you can create a custom `WeightToFee` function which always adds an additional amount of fee on top of any inputted Weight.

So something like:

```
/// Implementor of `WeightToFee` that maps one unit of weight
/// to one unit of fee, and always adds an extra `E` fee on top.
pub struct IdentityFeeWithConstantExtra<T, E>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<(T, E)>);

impl<T, E> WeightToFee for IdentityFeeWithConstantExtra<T, E>
where
    T: BaseArithmetic + From<u32> + Copy + Unsigned,
    E: Get<T>,
{
    type Balance = T;

    fn weight_to_fee(weight: &Weight) -> Self::Balance {
        let base = Self::Balance::saturated_from(*weight);
        base.saturating_add(E::get())
    }
}
```